# WhatsApp not listed by queryIntentActivities android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I'm trying to list all the apps which have the intent which allows you to send messages, I believe it to be ACTION_SEND.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
List<ResolveInfo> theList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mIntent, 0);

Log.d("TEST", " TEST");
```

When I  put a breakpoint at the log, whatsapp does not appear in the list, but vyber does.

Comment: I experienced apps missing when I got no text to send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a MIME type to the `Intent`, representing the type of data that you intend to share.

As it stands, you are not going to match activities with an `<intent-filter>` for `ACTION_SEND` that stipulate what MIME types that they support.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines :

```
        mIntent.setType("text/plain");
        mIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your text to share");
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than adding the MIME type to the `Intent` as @CommonsWare suggests, after Android 11 you will also need to add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
</queries>
```